# escape string before executing with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a set of ip addresses declared to a variable `IP`

```
IP=["https://127.0.0.1", "https://127.0.0.2", "https://127.0.0.3"]
```

Need to subtitute the value of `IP` in some file so i use the sed command

```
sed -i 's/#hosts: \["https:\/\/localhost:80"\]/hosts: ['$IP']/g' someFile
```

This errors out with

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 84: unknown option to `s'
```

So i tried, which works fine, notice the `\` escapes on the IP addresses

```
sed -i 's/#hosts: \["https:\/\/localhost:80"\]/hosts:["https:\/\/127.0.0.1", "https:\/\/127.0.0.2", "https:\/\/127.0.0.3"]/g'
```

expected results:

```
hosts: ["https://127.0.0.1", "https://127.0.0.2", "https://127.0.0.3"]
```

I can't really influence the value of `IP` variable because it's gotten from a parameter store with other applications using it. I'm assuming I need to write a function to do the escapes after getting the value from the parameter store? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is you're using `sed's` default script delimiter of `/`, which also shows up in the data/strings you're processing, with the net result being that `sed` can't tell which `/` are script delimiters vs data.

One solution, as you've figured out, is to escape the `/` that show up as data.

Another solution is to use a different character (that doesn's show up in the data) as the `sed` script delimiter.

Addressing a couple other issues with the current code, and using `|` as the `sed` script delimiter:

```
IP='["https://127.0.0.1", "https://127.0.0.2", "https://127.0.0.3"]'  # wrap value in single quotes so the whole line is treated as part of the assignment to IP

sed -i "s|#hosts: \[https://localhost:80\]|hosts: $IP|g" someFile   # wrap script in double quotes to allow for expansion of $IP
```

This generates:

```
$ cat someFile
hosts: ["https://127.0.0.1", "https://127.0.0.2", "https://127.0.0.3"]
```